# How to handle POST net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in Axios Vue.js django

Tags: javascript, django, database, vue.js, axios

I am using Axios to send the data for the backend but it keeps breaking, what should I do?

in `.then(response => { this.$router.push('/Log-in') return response })`, I returned the "response" because the console is saying "error  'response' is defined but never used"

**vue.js file**

```
import axios from 'axios'
if (!this.errors.length) {
  const formData = {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password,
    email: this.email
  }

  axios
    .post('/api/v1/users', formData)
    .then(response => {
      this.$router.push('/Log-in')
      return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        for (const property in error.response.data) {
          this.errors.push(`${property}: ${error.response.data[property]}`)
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      } else if (error.massege) {
        this.errors.push('Something went wrong, Please try again!')
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    })
}
```

**setting.py django**

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost:8000',
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Here's how I solved it:

1. Install django-cors-headers by executing the following in your terminal:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

2. In your settings.py file, insert the following:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   ...,
   "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
   "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
   'http://localhost:8000',
   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
]
```

Then that should do it. If not, then here's step 3):

3. In your settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...,
   "corsheader"
   ...,
]
```

From the django-cors-headers 3.14.0 package documentation:

> This [django-cors-headers] allows in-browser requests to your Django application from other origins.

You can access the package and read more about it by following this link: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

I hope this helped.